# Pandas Dataframe interpolating in sections delimited by indexes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

My sample code is as follow:

```
import pandas as pd


dictx = {'col1':[1,'nan','nan','nan',5,'nan',7,'nan',9,'nan','nan','nan',13],\
    'col2':[20,'nan','nan','nan',22,'nan',25,'nan',30,'nan','nan','nan',25],\
    'col3':[15,'nan','nan','nan',10,'nan',14,'nan',13,'nan','nan','nan',9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictx).astype(float)
```

I'm trying to interpolate various segments which contain the value 'nan'.
For context, I'm trying to track bus speeds using GPS data provided by the city (São Paulo, Brazil), but the data is scarce and with parts that do not provide the information, as the e.g., but there're segments which I know for a fact that they are stopped, such as dawn, but the information come as 'nan' as well.

What I need:
I've been experimenting with `dataframe.interpolate()` parameters (limit and limit_diretcion) but came up short. If I set `df.interpolate(limit=2)` I will not only interpolate the data that I need but the data where it shouldn't. **So I need to interpolate between sections defined by a limit**

Desired output:

```
Out[7]: 
    col1   col2   col3
0    1.0  20.00  15.00
1    nan  nan    nan
2    nan  nan    nan
3    nan  nan    nan
4    5.0  22.00  10.00
5    6.0  23.50  12.00
6    7.0  25.00  14.00
7    8.0  27.50  13.50
8    9.0  30.00  13.00
9    nan  nan    nan
10   nan  nan    nan
11   nan  nan    nan
12   13.0 25.00  9.00
```

The logic that I've been trying to apply is basically trying to find nan's and calculating the difference between their indexes and so createing a new dataframe_temp to interpolate and only than add it to another creating a new dataframe_final. But this has become hard to achieve due to the fact that `'nan'=='nan'` return `False`

Comment: So the logic is, interpolate only sequences of one or two `nan` values, but leave as they are longer sequences, right?

Comment: Basically it's, but in the original code this sequences of `nan` can be up to 30, sometimes 60!

Comment: Updated answer to be more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack but may still be useful.  Likely Pandas 0.23 will have a better solution.

https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#dataframe-interpolate-has-gained-the-limit-area-kwarg

```
df_fw = df.interpolate(limit=1)
df_bk = df.interpolate(limit=1, limit_direction='backward')

df_fw.where(df_bk.notna())

    col1  col2  col3
0    1.0  20.0  15.0
1    NaN   NaN   NaN
2    NaN   NaN   NaN
3    NaN   NaN   NaN
4    5.0  22.0  10.0
5    6.0  23.5  12.0
6    7.0  25.0  14.0
7    8.0  27.5  13.5
8    9.0  30.0  13.0
9    NaN   NaN   NaN
10   NaN   NaN   NaN
11   NaN   NaN   NaN
12  13.0  25.0   9.0
```

---

**Not a Hack**
More legitimate way of handling it.
Generalized to handle any limit.

```
def interp(df, limit):
    d = df.notna().rolling(limit + 1).agg(any).fillna(1)
    d = pd.concat({
        i: d.shift(-i).fillna(1)
        for i in range(limit + 1)
    }).prod(level=1)

    return df.interpolate(limit=limit).where(d.astype(bool))

df.pipe(interp, 1)

    col1  col2  col3
0    1.0  20.0  15.0
1    NaN   NaN   NaN
2    NaN   NaN   NaN
3    NaN   NaN   NaN
4    5.0  22.0  10.0
5    6.0  23.5  12.0
6    7.0  25.0  14.0
7    8.0  27.5  13.5
8    9.0  30.0  13.0
9    NaN   NaN   NaN
10   NaN   NaN   NaN
11   NaN   NaN   NaN
12  13.0  25.0   9.0
```

Can also handle variation in `NaN` from column to column.  Consider a different `df`

```
dictx = {'col1':[1,'nan','nan','nan',5,'nan','nan',7,'nan',9,'nan','nan','nan',13],\
    'col2':[20,'nan','nan','nan',22,'nan',25,'nan','nan',30,'nan','nan','nan',25],\
    'col3':[15,'nan','nan','nan',10,'nan',14,'nan',13,'nan','nan','nan',9,'nan']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictx).astype(float)
df

    col1  col2  col3
0    1.0  20.0  15.0
1    NaN   NaN   NaN
2    NaN   NaN   NaN
3    NaN   NaN   NaN
4    5.0  22.0  10.0
5    NaN   NaN   NaN
6    NaN  25.0  14.0
7    7.0   NaN   NaN
8    NaN   NaN  13.0
9    9.0  30.0   NaN
10   NaN   NaN   NaN
11   NaN   NaN   NaN
12   NaN   NaN   9.0
13  13.0  25.0   NaN
```

Then with `limit=1`

```
df.pipe(interp, 1)

    col1  col2  col3
0    1.0  20.0  15.0
1    NaN   NaN   NaN
2    NaN   NaN   NaN
3    NaN   NaN   NaN
4    5.0  22.0  10.0
5    NaN  23.5  12.0
6    NaN  25.0  14.0
7    7.0   NaN  13.5
8    8.0   NaN  13.0
9    9.0  30.0   NaN
10   NaN   NaN   NaN
11   NaN   NaN   NaN
12   NaN   NaN   9.0
13  13.0  25.0   9.0
```

And with `limit=2`

```
df.pipe(interp, 2).round(2)

     col1   col2  col3
0    1.00  20.00  15.0
1     NaN    NaN   NaN
2     NaN    NaN   NaN
3     NaN    NaN   NaN
4    5.00  22.00  10.0
5    5.67  23.50  12.0
6    6.33  25.00  14.0
7    7.00  26.67  13.5
8    8.00  28.33  13.0
9    9.00  30.00   NaN
10    NaN    NaN   NaN
11    NaN    NaN   NaN
12    NaN    NaN   9.0
13  13.00  25.00   9.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I want to know how do you study? Do you use books? I've been trying to improve my coding habilities but I don't think I'd ever came up with what you and @unutbu proposed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to selectively ignore rows which are consecutive runs of NaNs whose length is greater than a certain size (given by `limit`):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dictx = {'col1':[1,'nan','nan','nan',5,'nan',7,'nan',9,'nan','nan','nan',13],\
    'col2':[20,'nan','nan','nan',22,'nan',25,'nan',30,'nan','nan','nan',25],\
    'col3':[15,'nan','nan','nan',10,'nan',14,'nan',13,'nan','nan','nan',9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictx).astype(float)

limit = 2
notnull = pd.notnull(df).all(axis=1)
# assign group numbers to the rows of df. Each group starts with a non-null row,
# followed by null rows
group = notnull.cumsum()
# find the index of groups having length > limit
ignore = (df.groupby(group).filter(lambda grp: len(grp)>limit)).index
# only ignore rows which are null
ignore = df.loc[~notnull].index.intersection(ignore)
keep = df.index.difference(ignore)
# interpolate only the kept rows
df.loc[keep] = df.loc[keep].interpolate()

print(df)
```

prints

```
    col1  col2  col3
0    1.0  20.0  15.0
1    NaN   NaN   NaN
2    NaN   NaN   NaN
3    NaN   NaN   NaN
4    5.0  22.0  10.0
5    6.0  23.5  12.0
6    7.0  25.0  14.0
7    8.0  27.5  13.5
8    9.0  30.0  13.0
9    NaN   NaN   NaN
10   NaN   NaN   NaN
11   NaN   NaN   NaN
12  13.0  25.0   9.0
```

By changing the value of `limit` you can control how big the group has to be before it should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer.

```
for i in list(df):

     for x in range(len(df[i])):

         if not df[i][x]  > -100:

                   df[i][x] = 0

df

col1    col2    col3
0   1.0     20.0    15.0
1   0.0     0.0     0.0
2   0.0     0.0     0.0
3   0.0     0.0     0.0
4   5.0     22.0    10.0
5   0.0     0.0     0.0
6   7.0     25.0    14.0
7   0.0     0.0     0.0
8   9.0     30.0    13.0
9   0.0     0.0     0.0
10  0.0     0.0     0.0
11  0.0     0.0     0.0
12  13.0    25.0    9.0
```

Now,

```
df["col1"][1] == df["col2"][1]
True
```