# Using pandas.interpolate()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

Suppose

```
test = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,5,6,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,4,np.nan])
```

I would like to apply following command:

```
test.interpolate(limit = 2, limit_direction  = 'both', limit_area = 'inside')
```

which returns

```
           0
0   1.000000
1   2.000000
2   3.000000
3   3.166667
4   3.333333
5        NaN
6   3.666667
7   3.833333
8   4.000000
9   5.000000
10  6.000000
11  5.500000
12  5.000000
13       NaN
14  4.000000
15  3.500000
16  3.000000
17  4.000000
18       NaN
```

Question: How can i apply a restriction on the minimum number of valid numbers (i.e not NaN) before AND after a group of NaNs, so as to apply the interpolation

In this example, i would like to fill first group of NaNs because there are minimum 3 valid numbers before AND after, but NOT interpolate the second group of NaNs, as there are only two valid numbers after the NaNs (and not 3 as i would prefer)

Expected result:

```
           0
0   1.000000
1   2.000000
2   3.000000
3   3.166667
4   3.333333
5        NaN
6   3.666667
7   3.833333
8   4.000000
9   5.000000
10  6.000000
11       NaN
12       NaN
13       NaN
14       NaN
15       NaN
16  3.000000
17  4.000000
18       NaN
```

Comment: decided to remove my fist answer since it is missleading. what you *could* do is set values to NaN if they are found in blocks of which the size is below a certain threshold and then call the interpolation. But that seems a somewhat bulky solution... maybe a better [solution in this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933165/pandas-dataframe-interpolating-in-sections-delimited-by-indexes)?

Comment: My problem is not the size of the NaN blocks ( as i address this with limit and limit_direction ) but instead i need to check the size of the (not NaN) blocks before AND after the NaN block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 1: revised my first answer. One more go with some sort of mask approach based on [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721674/find-consecutive-repeated-nan-in-a-numpy-array).
EDIT 2: added copy back to pd df using `deepcopy` to avoid the copy-by-reference issue.

```py
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from copy import deepcopy

    a = np.array([1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,5,6,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,4,np.nan,1])

    df = pd.DataFrame(a)
    # store values for later, to keep information from blocks that are below size limit:
    temp = deepcopy(df[df[0].notnull()]) 

    mask = np.concatenate(([False],np.isfinite(a),[False]))
    idx = np.nonzero(mask[1:] != mask[:-1])[0] # start and stop indices of your blocks of finite numbers
    counts = (np.flatnonzero(mask[1:] < mask[:-1]) - np.flatnonzero(mask[1:] > mask[:-1])) # n finite numbers per block

    sz_limit = 2 # set limit, exclusive in this case
    for i, size in enumerate(counts):
        if size <= sz_limit:
            a[idx[i*2]:idx[i*2+1]] = np.nan
```

now call the interpolation and write back values from 'too small' blocks:

```py
    a_inter = pd.DataFrame(a).interpolate(limit = 2, limit_direction = 'both', limit_area = 'inside') 
    a_inter.update(other = temp)
```

`a_inter` is then

```py
           0
0   1.000000
1   2.000000
2   3.000000
3   3.166667
4   3.333333
5        NaN
6   3.666667
7   3.833333
8   4.000000
9   5.000000
10  6.000000
11       NaN
12       NaN
13       NaN
14       NaN
15       NaN
16       NaN
17       NaN
18       NaN
```

to improve this hack, you could put the masking in a function and get rid of the for loop.

Comment: i tried your prosposed mask, but i not sure if a can use it. My intended mask, would set False to the NaN values which i dont want to be interpolated as stated in my Question, so that i can then apply pd.interpolate() for the True values only

Comment: `a_inter = pd.DataFrame(a).interpolate(limit = 2, limit_direction  = 'both', limit_area = 'inside')`

`temp = df[df[0].notnull()]`

`a_inter.update(other = temp)` , where df is your initial a array in dataframe format

Comment: glad I could help! I'll maybe try to get rid of the for loop some other time ;-)

Comment: update: unfortunaterly when trying for 
`a = np.array([1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,5,6,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,4,np.nan,1])` (i added one number in the end), it wont work correctly as it replaces 3.4 with NaNs

Comment: @NSK, I made an edit, what you encountered actually was a copy-by-reference bug, `temp = df[df[0].notnull()]` just copies the reference, but you need a copy of the value.